# How to make a request in Postman

Tags: web-services, http, post, postman

[Arabam](https://www.arabam.com/) is an e-commerce site that I am attempting to query. As an example, given [the automobile page](https://www.arabam.com/ikinci-el/otomobil), you can add query parameters to the page such as `days` and `sort` as follows:

https://www.arabam.com/ikinci-el/otomobil?days=30&sort=startedAt.desc

I will be accessing the data via their API, however, which lives at:

https://api.arabam.com/listing/v2/search

And here is the API Key I'm using:

```
_V85Kref7xGZHc1XRpUmOhDDd07zhZTOvUSIbJe_sSNHSDV79EjODA==
```

I am able to make the request using Postman:

[image]

But whichever query parameters I pass, the total number of keys in the response remains the same. How do I pass parameters correctly? Either I am not passing them correctly, or these are not the correct parameters. How do I find correct parameters?

I'm relatively new to this so need a bit of guidance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've reworded your question to help clarify the request, and have included your image inline so it's easier to view as part of the request. As part of this, I have kept your API Key, but you should be _really_ wary of sharing this publicly; often, API keys act similar to a password, and provide people who have it with the same permissions granted to you. You may consider invalidating this API key and requesting a new one to ensure that your account is not compromised.

Comment: As far as your actual question, the query string parameters are generally defined by the develop of the web service, so you'll need to find documentation from Arabam to understand what the valid options are. It's important to note that those may not be the same as the ones used on their front-end website. Sometimes, they're just different names; other times, they fundamentally different structures. For instance, `days` might be replaced with `sinceDate`. Regardless, it's unlikely that the Stack Overflow community will be able to help identify those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried posting the params as a json body instead